# How to analyse data after applying pandas' groupby function?

Tags: python, dataset, pandas

I have a data set of Olympic games medal winners. I am trying to find the country with most medals. How do I go about working with the series after applying groupby function?

Here is my data frame.

```
    ID  Name        Sex   Age    City        Sport      Medal
 0  1   A Dijiang   M     24.0   Barcelona  Basketball  Gold
 1  2   A Lamusi    M     23.0   London     Judo        Silver
 ...
```

I applied the following function to my data frame called qq:

```
zz = qq[qq.Medal =='Gold'].groupby(['NOC', 'Medal'])
zz.Medal.value_counts()

NOC  Medal  Medal
ALG  Gold   Gold        5
ANZ  Gold   Gold       20
ARG  Gold   Gold       91
ARM  Gold   Gold        2
```

After applying the function how can I analyse this zz series?

For example how can I return the country with maximum medals? 
If I groupby without 'Gold' medal constraint, how can I count the sum of medals for each country?

Comment: Does each and every record have a medal? In that case remove the `qq.Medal =='Gold'` and `'Medal'`.

Comment: No. Not every country won a medal.

Comment: what are the possible values in `Medal` column?

Comment: Gold Silver Bronze NaN

Answer (score 0):

You need to first filter out  the `NaN` medals, and then aggregate. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['USA', 'Gold'],
                   ['USA', 'Bronze'],
                   ['USA', 'NaN'],
                   ['UK', 'Silver'],
                   ['UK', 'NaN']],
                  columns=['NOC', 'Medal'])

valid_medals = df[df['Medal'] != 'NaN']
medal_count = valid_medals.groupby(['NOC'], as_index=False)\
    .count().sort_values(by=['Medal'],ascending=False)
print(medal_count)
print('Top country:')
print(medal_count.iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
   NOC  Medal
1  USA      2
0   UK      1
Top country:
NOC      USA
Medal      2
Name: 1, dtype: object
```